# Letterpress Printing

Tags: steganography

[image]

A bed of 5x13 movable slugs cast typesetting was composed for printing a part of publication on the daily paper. But someone  mess up with the locks and shuffled the message by swapping two rows then two columns of letters. And again repeat swapping two rows then two columns of letters for few more times until the bed is completely random as shown above. When the composer noticed this, he simply revert it before the inking and paper press. What should be printed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> [image]
>  `ENERGY EQUALS THE REST MASS MULTIPLIED BY THE SQUARE OF LIGHT'S SPEED`.

How I got it:

> I figured that an S is the most likely thing to go after an apostrophe. When that S is taken out, the rest of the row anagrams to `LIGHTSPEED`; and once you put `LIGHT` together by rearranging columns, the rest of the rows *also* start spelling out words, and then it's easy to see what works.